# Is there a global var keyword defined in strict mode?

Tags: javascript

Sloppy Mode (nonstrict mode):

---

```
function sloppyFunc() {
   sloppyVar = 123;
}
sloppyFunc(); // creates global variable `sloppyVar`
console.log(sloppyVar); // 123
```

Strict Mode:

---

```
function strictFunc(){
   'use strict';
   strictVar = 123;
}
strictFunc(); // ReferenceError: strictVar is not defined
```

Is there a way to declare a global variable in strict mode inside function block?

Comment: You can directly attach the variable to the global object (see answer) but normally you write `"use strict"` when you want a clean code, not when you want your functions to declare global variables.

Comment: yeah, I just wanted to know while reading a book, thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read and write properties to window.

```
function strictFunc(){
   'use strict';
   window.strictVar = 123;
}
strictFunc(); 
console.log(strictVar); // 123
```

dystroy reminded me that this would only work in a browser. In the interest of providing a complete answer, here's how you do it in node.js:

```
function strictFunc(){
   'use strict';
   GLOBAL.strictVar = 123;
}
strictFunc();
```

Comment: @parchment I really forgot about window.

Comment: Or, if calling it just like that, `this.strictVar` should also work.

Comment: @Scimonster But this is used for instances, no?

Comment: @C-linkNepal Yes, unbound functions are executed with `this` set to the global.

Comment: I mean, bound to a certain context, such as with function.call(mycontext)

Answer (score 0):

```
var strictVar; //declare strictVar in global scope for later usage
function strictFunc() {
    'use strict';
    strictVar = 123; //set strictVar to 123
}

strictFunc(); //call strictFunc();
console.log(strictVar); // => 123
```

It's bad practise to define variables without the "var" keyword for usage in the global scope. That's why it's not possible in strict mode. You have to declare that variable in the global scope first by using the var keyword. Then you can set its value in a function.

Comment: I really mentioned to use inside function block. Thanks anyway.